# Ag / Grep Exact Match Only Search

Tags: grep, ack, ag

I am having an issue with using [Ag (The Silver Searcher)](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)...

In the docs it says to use `-Q` for exact match, but I don't understand why it does not work for my purposes. If I type something like `ag -Q actions` or `ag -Q 'actions'` into my terminal, it returns all instances of `actions`, including things like `transactions` and any other strings that `actions` is part of.

I have tried a couple other combinations of flags from the docs, including `-s` and `-S`, among others, but still I cannot get strictly strings matching *just* `actions` to return for me.

I can't get this to work with `grep` either. Does anyone know how I can get what I need with `ag`? (*or even with `grep`*)...?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because ag (and grep), find files that *contain* something. `ag -Q` means to interpret the search as an exact literal string, not a fuzzy string or a regex. Okay. But a file that has the word "transactions" in it contains *exactly, literally* the character sequence `actions`. Sure, it contains more than that too, but that's not surprising.

Probably you're looking for a word-boundary search, `grep '\bactions\b'` or `ag -w -Q actions` (maybe `ag -w -Q -s actions`). But that is not at all the same thing as "*just* actions", it's a specific requirement on the things *surrounding* "actions" (namely that they be the beginning or end of a line, or non-letter characters). You have to tell the computer what you actually mean.

Comment: Thank you!! That is exactly what I was looking for!! Coulda sworn I tried that as part of the many combinations I've tried, but it seems to work now, so great! Thanks again...